# Horizontal ScrollableDatatable in richfaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces, scrollable

I'm posting atleast one question a day. :)
I'm working with JSF2.0 and Richfaces 4.X. I've a List of Images that I want to display in my page. I want them display in a ScrollableDataTable having only 1 row of images. So that the Images will be like a horizontal bar. Here is my code.

```
         <h:panelGrid>
                            <rich:scrollableDataTable width="100px" height="100px" frozenColCount="0" rows="1" value="#{startupBean.colorList}"  var="colorBO">
                                <rich:column width="100px">
                                    <f:facet name="header" >
                                      <h:outputText value="Colors"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <a4j:commandLink id="color" actionListener="#{startupBean.getColor}"> 
                                         <h:graphicImage width="100px" height="100px" id="colors" alt="jsf-sun" url="#{colorBO.color_url}" value="#{colorBO.color_url}" binding="#{startupBean.graphicColor}" > 
                                        </h:graphicImage> 
                                    </a4j:commandLink>

                                </rich:column>
                        </rich:scrollableDataTable>
                    </h:panelGrid>
```

I've tried juggling the Datatable and the column attributes with no luck. The problem is, if I give rows=1 in the datatable, only the first image from the list is displayed. If I dont give rows=1, then the entire list is displayed vertically.

Can anyone please tell me if there is a workaround for this?

Thanks,
Jane

Answer (score 0):

I'm using dataGrid to achieve this instead of ScrollableDataTable.

Thanks,
Jane

Comment: You don't need to post an answer to add info for your question. Instead, edit your question.